# Is it possible to change browser icon(in taskBar) using C# for website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

My client asked me to **change  the default Browser Logo to Website Logo(in task Bar)**.I have searched for the various ways to achieve it.But all my trails went wrong.May i know **whether it possible for a  C# ASP Website**.Please help me to complete this.

[image]

I don't know this is a correct question or not.If you said its possibility,It might be very helpful for me.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: I have never seen anyone do this before, thus I think it is not possible. However I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

The browser icon is the icon chosen for that particular piece of software, for that operating system.

You could set a `favicon`, which with some browsers may change the software icon, but this is not something you will be able to do consistently.

Comment: Thank you Curt.I have added favicon to my website .I will discuss with client about this.